# Preview different between UIActivityViewController and UIPrintInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, uiimage

I used `UIActivityViewController` to replace `UIPrintInteractionController` but noticed that for the same UIImage, if I select Print, the Print screen bought up by `UIActivityViewController` has a preview that's like a scaled / cropped version of the original `UIImage`, is there anything I missed? I assumed they are internally the same Print view controller but why there's a difference for the same image?